# The fonts in a page becomes large whenever the browser is full screen, but i don't want it anymore

Tags: html, css

I was trying to adjust the fonts in my html page according to the screen size.
I was using

```
body{
   font-size:1vmax;
}
```

but when i decided to not use it anymore, the font is still changes according to the screen size. It seems fine when i not reference the css code though.. can anyone help me?
here is my html code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Kokeru</title>

    <!-- fonts -->
    <!-- raleway for kokeru title -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:ital,wght@1,600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- custom styling -->
    <link href="assets/css/custom-style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar py-0">
        <a class="navbar-brand " href="#" id="kokeruBrand">Kokeru</a>

        <a class="my-0 ml-auto mr-5 py-0" href="#">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="button">Login</button>
        </a>

    <!-- navbar -->
    </nav>

    <!-- penjelasan kokeru -->
    <!-- beserta tanggal dan jam -->
    <div class="text-center" id="penjelasanKokeru">
        <h2>Monitoring Kebersihan dan Kerapihan Ruangan<br>Gedung Bersama Maju</h2>
        <h3>Hari Minggu Tanggal 13 Desember 2020 Jam 11:11</h3>
    </div>

    <!-- ruangan2nya -->
    <div class="container-fluid my-5">
        <div class="row">
            <a href="#" class="card-link col-lg-2">
                <div class="card mx-3 px-0">
                    <div class="card-body text-center">
                            <h4 class="card-title text-center">R.123</h4>
                            BELUM<br>
                            Hilmi<br>
                            click for more detail
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>

            <a href="#" class="card-link col-lg-2">
                <div class="card mx-3 px-0" style="width: 13rem;">
                    <div class="card-body text-center">
                            <h4 class="card-title text-center">R.123</h4>
                            BELUM<br>
                            Hilmi<br>
                            click for more detail
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>

            <a href="#" class="card-link col-lg-2">
                <div class="card mx-3 px-0" style="width: 13rem;">
                    <div class="card-body text-center">
                            <h4 class="card-title text-center">R.123</h4>
                            BELUM<br>
                            Hilmi<br>
                            click for more detail
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>

            <a href="#" class="card-link col-lg-2">
                <div class="card mx-3 px-0" style="width: 13rem;">
                    <div class="card-body text-center">
                            <h4 class="card-title text-center">R.123</h4>
                            BELUM<br>
                            Hilmi<br>
                            click for more detail
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>

            <a href="#" class="card-link col-lg-2">
                <div class="card mx-3 px-0" style="width: 13rem;">
                    <div class="card-body text-center">
                            <h4 class="card-title text-center">R.123</h4>
                            BELUM<br>
                            Hilmi<br>
                            click for more detail
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="card-link col-lg-2">
                <div class="card mx-3 px-0" style="width: 13rem;">
                    <div class="card-body text-center">
                            <h4 class="card-title text-center">R.123</h4>
                            BELUM<br>
                            Hilmi<br>
                            click for more detail
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>


        <!-- row -->
        </div>
    <!-- ruangan2nya -->
    </div>

    <!-- Option 2: jQuery, Popper.js, and Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

here is my custom-style.css code :

```
body{
    background-color: #bed0ca;
    /* font-size: 1vmax; */
}

#kokeruBrand{
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

nav{
    background-color: #e3f2fd;
}

#penjelasanKokeru{
    color: blue;
}

/* a.card-link, 
a.card-link:hover {
    color: inherit;
} */
/* 
@media screen and (max-width : 320)
{
  body
  {
    font:1.5rem;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width : 1204px)
{
  body
  {
    font:2.5rem;
  }
} */
```

Comment: take a look at the styling used via your browsers inspector/developer-tools you are probably still using a cached version of your stylesheet. Ctrl+F5 should force a reload.

Answer (score 1):

according to the comment, it seems that i still use my cached version of my stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

According to the comment, and like the Wechuck's answer,

> take a look at the styling used via your browsers inspector/developer-tools you are probably still using a cached version of your stylesheet. Ctrl+F5 should force a reload.

> according to the comment, it seems that i still use my cached version of my stylesheet.

You should reload the browser with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>
Or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>